# How to distinct values from a 2D Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I got an 2d Array filled by a Database like this:

```
var Index = [["value1_lang1", "value1_lang2", "value1_lang3", "3,6,11,"],["value1_lang1", "value1_lang2", "value1_lang3", "37,41,97,114,"],["value2_lang1", "value2_lang2", "value2_lang3", "9,14,33,"]];
```

The array will got over 600 values. I try to do it with the following two for loops:

```
for(var i = 0; i < Index.length; i++) {
 for(var j = i + 1; j < Index.length; ) {
  var item1 = Index[i][0]; //Only have to compare the values from lang1
  var item2 = Index[j][0];

  if(item1 == item2) {
   var page1 = Index[i][3];
   var page2 = Index[j][3];

   if(page1 != page2) {
    var newpages = page1 + page2;
   } else {
    var newpages = page1;
   }

   Index[i][3] = newpages;
   Index.splice(j, 1);
   page1 = "";
   page2 = "";
   newpages = "";

  } else {
   j++;
  }
 }
}
```

The result should look like this:

```
var Index = [["value1_lang1", "value1_lang2", "value1_lang3", "3,6,11,37,41,97,114"], ["value2_lang1", "value2_lang2", "value2_lang3", "9,14,33,"]];
```

But the real result looks like this:

```
var Index = [[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined],["value1_lang1", "value1_lang2", "value1_lang3", "3,6,11,37,41,97,114,"], ["value2_lang1", "value2_lang2", "value2_lang3", "9,14,33,"]];
```

Comment: Your result has bracket mismatch, hence, not clear with the desired result. Can you please correct that?

Comment: Did you mean `if(item1 == item2)` ?

Comment: @nikhil thanks for the hint!

Comment: @DeepakKumar Yes!

Comment: So, basically you want to concatenate the arrays based on first value? Correct? Also, there is an assumption of 2nd and 3rd value to be always same if the first value is same?

Comment: I'm able to run your code in Chrome console with change of `y` to `j`. And I'm getting the desired variable Index as output. Can you check again? Also make the change `newpages = page1 + "," + page2`

Comment: Sorry, had to editied again. The "," is always at the end of the page numbers. It works but is this the best way to do it?

Comment: @nikhil the first, second and third values are the productnames in different languages. So if Index[i][0] == Index[j][0] is true , Index[i][1] == Index[j][1] etc are true too.

Comment: Thank you for sharing information. Please check my answer. Seems like it will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the first three elements of the inner array as key for a hash table and push to the result set, if not exist or append the element at index 3.

```js
var data = [["value1_lang1", "value1_lang2", "value1_lang3", "3,6,11,"], ["value1_lang1", "value1_lang2", "value1_lang3", "37,41,97,114,"], ["value2_lang1", "value2_lang2", "value2_lang3", "9,14,33,"]],
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    var key = a.slice(0, 3).join('|');
    if (!this[key]) {
        this[key] = a.slice();
        result.push(this[key]);
        return;
    }
    this[key][3] += a[3];
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my assumption on the requirement, following should work for you

```js
var Index = [
  ["value1_lang1", "value1_lang2", "value1_lang3", "3,6,11"],
  ["value1_lang1", "value1_lang2", "value1_lang3", "37,41,97,114"],
  ["value2_lang1", "value2_lang2", "value2_lang3", "9,14,33"]
];

var map = {}; // Creating a map of unique values and value (will get updated)

for (var item of Index) {
  var val = map[item[0]];
  if (val) {
    val[3] = val[3] + item.slice(3).join(",");
  } else {
    val = item;
  }
  map[item[0]] = val;
}

var result = []; // Will be a collection of desired values
for (var key in map) {
  result.push(map[key]);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```